# Random walk on integers keeping direction with prob $p$ and changing direction with prob $1-p$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> An insect moves on the integers in steps $\pm 1$, in a way that it keeps its direction with prob $p$ and changes direction with prob $1-p$. Its position at time $t=0$ is $0$ (coming from $-1$).
>
> (1)  Define a Markov chain that describes the insect's movement and find the transition probabilities.
>
> (2)  Find the probability the insect reaches state $N$ before it reaches $-N$.

*Attempt.* Let $X_n$ be the insect's position after $n$ steps. Then
$X_n$ takes values on integers and if fact $X_{2n}$ takes values $-2n,\ldots,-2,0,2,\ldots,2n$ (for example
$$P(X_2=+2)=p^2,~P(X_2=0)=(1-p)p+(1-p)^2,~P(X_2=-2)=(1-p)p)$$
and $X_{2n+1}$ takes values $-2n-1,\ldots,-1,1,\ldots,2n+1$.
As for the transition probabilities, if $X_{2n}=2k$ then the probability $X_{2n+1}=2k+1$ equals:
$$p\times \textrm{number of ways to reach position $2k$ from left in $2n$ steps}~+$$
$$(1-p)\times \textrm{number of ways to reach position $2k$ from right in $2n$ steps}~~~(\star).$$
Of course $$P(X_{2n+1}=2k-1\mid X_{2n}=2k)=1-P(X_{2n+1}=2k+1\mid X_{2n}=2k),$$
$$P(X_{2n}=2k\mid X_{2n-1}=2k-1)=\ldots~(\textrm{as above}),$$
$$P(X_{2n}=2k-2\mid X_{2n-1}=2k-1)=1-P(X_{2n}=2k\mid X_{2n-1}=2k-1).$$

I have stuck on evaluating the above number of ways in ($\star$).

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The problem with your approach is that, unless $p=\frac12$, $(X_n)$ is not a Markov chain. So, you must first solve the question: "Define a Markov chain that describes the insect's movement".

Comment: An important part of defining a Markov process to describe a situation is ensuring that the state variable contains sufficient information that the process is in fact Markov. This means that you need to be able to fully deduce the distribution of $X_{n+1}$ when all you know is $X_n$ (and $n$, if the process is time inhomogeneous). In this situation the position does not encapsulate enough information for the process to be Markov (unless $p=1/2$ in which case this is just the simple symmetric random walk). You need the velocity to be built into the state variable as well.

Comment: How about defining $X_n$ as +1 if the $n-1$th step was to the right and $-1$ otherwise?

Comment: You need to say the position *and* the velocity, together. For that, $X_n$ can be a pair of integers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\peq{\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{}}$For the first question, denote $q = 1 - p$ and define $X_n \in \{1, -1\}$ to be the $n$-th move for $n \geqslant 0$, then $X_0 = 1$ and\begin{gather*}
P(X_{n + 1} = 1 \mid X_1, \cdots, X_n) = P(X_{n + 1} = 1 \mid X_n)\\
= p \cdot \frac{1 + X_n}{2} + q \cdot \frac{1 - X_n}{2},\\
P(X_{n + 1} = -1 \mid X_1, \cdots, X_n) = P(X_{n + 1} = -1 \mid X_n)\\
= p \cdot \frac{1 - X_n}{2} + q \cdot \frac{1 + X_n}{2},
\end{gather*}
which means $\{X_n\}$ is a Markov chain with respect to $\{\mathscr{F}_n\}$ where $\mathscr{F}_n = σ(X_1, \cdots, X_n)$.

Now for the second question, define $S_0 = 0$, $S_n = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n X_k$ for $n \geqslant 1$, $τ_a = \min\{n \geqslant 0 \mid S_n = a\}$, where $\min\varnothing := \infty$, and $τ = τ_N \land τ_{-N}$. It is easy to prove that $P(τ < \infty) = 1$. Note that the probability to be found is $P(τ_N < τ_{-N})$. Denote $c = \dfrac{p - q}{2q}$, then for $n \geqslant 0$,\begin{align*}
&\peq E(S_{n + 1} + cX_{n + 1} \mid \mathscr{F}_n) = S_n + (1 + c) E(X_{n + 1} \mid \mathscr{F}_n)\\
&= S_n + (1 + c)(pX_n + q(-X_n)) = S_n + cX_n,
\end{align*}
which implies $\{S_n + cX_n\}$ is a martingale. Note that for any $n \geqslant 0$, there is $|S_{τ \land n}| \leqslant N$ and $|X_{τ \land n}| = 1$, thus $\{S_{τ \land n} + cX_{τ \land n}\}$ is a bounded martingale. By the optional stopping time theorem,$$
E(S_τ + cX_τ) = E(S_0 + cX_0) = c.
$$
Note that$$
E(S_τ + cX_τ) = E((S_{τ_N} + cX_{τ_N}) I_{\{τ_N < τ_{-N}\}}) + E((S_{τ_{-N}} + cX_{τ_{-N}}) I_{\{τ_N > τ_{-N}\}}).
$$
Because $S_{τ_N} = N$ and $X_{τ_N} = 1$ on $\{τ_N < \infty\}$, and $S_{τ_{-N}} = -N$ and $X_{τ_{-N}} = -1$ on $\{τ_{-N} < \infty\}$, then\begin{gather*}
c = E(S_τ + cX_τ) = (N + c) P(τ_N < τ_{-N}) + (-N - c) P(τ_N > τ_{-N}),\\
1 = P(τ_N < τ_{-N}) + P(τ_N > τ_{-N})\\
\Longrightarrow P(τ_N < τ_{-N}) = \frac{N + 2c}{2N + 2c} = \frac{qN + (p - q)}{2qN + (p - q)}.
\end{gather*}

Comment: What is your definition of $X_n$? When is $X_n=+1$ and when is $X_n=-1$?

Comment: @NikolaosSkout If the insect makes a $+1$ move in the $n$-th step then $X_n=1$, otherwise $X_n=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your Markov chain should have two states per each position $n$, one for the case when the insect is looking left ($n_l$) and another for the opposite case ($n_r$). Then, by definition, in the basis $(\ldots,-1_l,-1_r,0_l,0_r,1_l,1_r,2_l,2_r,\ldots)$ the transition matrix will be (denote $q=1-p$):
$$ \left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr}
\ddots&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\
.&0&0&p&q&0&0&0&0&.\\
.&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&.\\
.&0&0&0&0&p&q&0&0&.\\
.&q&p&0&0&0&0&0&0&.\\
.&0&0&0&0&0&0&p&q&.\\
.&0&0&q&p&0&0&0&0&.\\
.&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&.\\
.&0&0&0&0&q&p&0&0&.\\
.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&\ddots\\
\end{array}\right) $$

Comment: This is the idea, yes, but your transition matrix seems incorrect. For example, from state $0_L$, one jumps either to $1_R$ or to $-1_L$.

Comment: @Did Yes, hence $p$ on the 1st ($=-1_l$th) and $q$ on the 6th ($=1_r$th) row at 3rd ($=0_l$th) column. When multiplied by $(.,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,.)^T$, the matrix gives $(.,p,0,0,0,0,q,0,0,.)^T$.

Comment: OK, I thought the transition matrix $Q$ used the convention that $Q(i,j)=P(Z_{n+1}=j\mid Z_n=i)$ but you are using $Q(i,j)=P(Z_{n+1}=i\mid Z_n=j)$. Clear now.